Ensure same seed generates same random numbers when using numpy and cupy
I import numpy or cupy as follows:
import numpy as np
# import cupy as np

Then I generate X as follows:
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.rand(4, 3)

I get two very different matrices depending on whether np is numpy or cupy.
numpy matrix:
[[0.5488135  0.71518937 0.60276338]
 [0.54488318 0.4236548  0.64589411]
 [0.43758721 0.891773   0.96366276]
 [0.38344152 0.79172504 0.52889492]]

cupy matrix:
[[0.43845084 0.4603647  0.25021471]
 [0.49474377 0.05301112 0.33769926]
 [0.39676252 0.87441866 0.48216683]
 [0.0428398  0.50841419 0.6545497 ]]

How can I generate the same random matrix using both numpy and cupy?

What makes you think this is possible?  numpy and cupy may use different random number generators.  I wouldn't be surprised if this was not possible even between early and late versions of numpy

Is this also an issue when using np.random.default_rng with the same seed? That is the newer version of random number generation that is now preferred (see more about this here).

To understand why it is not possible (efficiently) one need to understand how CPU and GPUs works. CPU have generally few cores and Numpy codes use only one of them for such an operation. Most RNG are based on a seed which is iteratively/sequentially updated to produce new numbers. Because of that, it is not possible to efficiently use the same RNG in parallel (only concurrently). This is also true on multiple cores.

GPUs are massively parallel devices while many wide SIMD units. Using only one iterative RNG on it would be so slow that it would be completely useless to use it (far slower than even low-end CPUs). Thus, the Cuda implementation needs to use many RNGs. To be more precise, the same RNG can be used but with different seed. Modern Nvidia GPUs have warp of 32 threads, >=2 warp per block can be scheduled in parallel per block, and blocks are scheduled on the dozens of SM. In practice there are generally as many seed as Cuda core, so typically thousands!

While it is possible to get the same result using the same method on CPU, it is not less efficient to do that on CPU (due to low-level reasons -- see below). 1 per-thread RNG is often enough on CPU. SIMD-friendly one can use as many seed as SIMD lanes but the number of seed needed is far smaller than on GPU because CPU SIMD units are not as wide as on GPU. Using too many seed (same as on GPU, but on CPU) causes the implementation to store data in memory rather than in registers due to register spilling which is detrimental for performance.

TL;DR: it's not possible to use the Numpy RNG on GPU (far too slow) and while it would be possible to use the Cuda one on CPU, but this is clearly sub-optimal (not trivial).

@JérômeRichard thanks for the detailed explanation. If you can post this as an answer, I think it would help others too. I can accept that one as the resolution as well.
